# Commercializing a php application?

Tags: php, web-applications

Say I have developed a php webapp and would like to distribute it for others to use as proprietary software.  Is there anything I can do short of some sort of licence or just trusting the customer to avoid having to provide a hosted solution?  Clearly if I just distribute the application to paying customers to host independently, I run the risk of them leaking the code.

Update:

Some of the responses so far suggest obfuscation.  However, this won't prevent another user from simply plopping the leaked obfuscated code onto their servers and reusing it.  Granted they won't be able to modify it..but I am looking for something more complete.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Obfuscating it can go a long way.  Many users won't try to figure out the logic.

You can also add a registration key -- something that calls the mothership and acts like a dongle.

**Edit:** What I was going for with the registration:  You can sell licenses by the domain, and require users to register their domain at your website after they buy.

One script I bought requires activation at their website.  (The script is obfuscated as well.)  Don't enter the domain, the software ceases working after a certain period of time.  Transfer domains, and the software ceases to work.

I don't know the mechanics but the basic idea is that you want to guarantee that the script is running at the domain the purchaser said it was running at.

Comment: Note that the registration key is only a reasonable approach if the code is also obfuscated.

Comment: Can you elaborate please on the registration key?  Will their be some logic in the code preventing it from running unless a valid registration key is obtained from another server?

Answer (score 1):

> Can you elaborate please on the registration key? Will their be some logic in the code preventing it from running unless a valid registration key is obtained from another server?

To do this, you would have to generate a key for the user when they purchased the application.  The application would then communicate with a master server which in turn looks up the key and checks the domain the key is coming from and sends back a simple true or false reading.  If the response is true, the application would then continue its operation, otherwise it would shutdown.

The only problem with this method is that if your master server were to ever go down, all of your clients would be locked out (unless you created a condition where if the master server was down, the default response would be true).

Comment: The client would just configure his firewall to block outgoing connections from the local webserver to the key validation server.

Comment: Oh I understand. Another problem, as I think someone else pointed out, is that this presupposes that the code is obfuscated and that the user cannot uncover (and remove) the logic preventing the code from running without the key.  I cannot seem to come up with a way around this.

Comment: There really isn't a way around it without obfuscating the code.  As long as the user has access to the raw source, they can do anything they want.

Comment: You can use a similar approach, but not require each licensee to connect to a master server, by including a non-obvious hashing algorithm in your app. So, you provide the key based on a host name and this gets stored in a config file; the code computes what the license key should be based on the host name and compares.

Comment: too bad there is no way to create some sort of binary in php and distribute that...i guess PHP being interpreted prevents this

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/search?q=php+code+obfuscator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Have at it...

This obfuscation usually consists of stripping comments and whitespace, base64 encoding, and sometimes other little tricks like completely renaming every variable and such to make it next to impossible to understand by humans

Answer (score 0):

Zend has a product "Zend Guard" (http://shop.zend.com/en/zend-guard.html) that may offer something more than obfuscation.

> With its key components of Encoding, Obfuscating and Licensing, Zend Guard protects your PHP applications from reverse engineering, unauthorized customization, unlicensed use and redistribution

Answer (score 0):

There's also ionCube. Generally these solutions require a server side extension to be loaded but most hosts will have them loaded already I find.

ionCube allows you to license to a particular domain if you like, and also allows you to put time limits on the script (to require license renewal).

Although by default ionCube is a system that requires you to actually create the licenses yourself, there is a system that you can buy to automatically manage this stuff for you (I thought it was PHP-Audit, though that site seems to have gone through a redesign and so I can't tell anymore).